# How to create a dynamic dropdown selection element whose option count changes according to the number to child a certain div has?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a div of certain id (say `#pageContent`) whose number of child element is going to change. I have a selection dropdown (say `pageSelection`)whose option count should match the number of children of `#pageContent`.
If the `#pageContent` child count is 10, the number of options in `pageSelection` should also be 10...

The last three options of the dropdown is to remain unchanged but the values must change accordingly. Initially the last three options have the value 2, 3 & 4.
If two more child elements are added to `#pageContent`, then the values of the last three options should now become 4, 5 & 6.
If 3 more child elements were added to `#pageContent`, then the values of the last three options should should have become 5, 6 & 7 and so on...

Here's my Code:

```js
function prependOptions() {
  var count = document.getElementById("pageContent").childElementCount;
  for (i = 0; i < count - 3; i++) {
    var index = i + 1;
    document.getElementById("pageSelection").prepend("<option value=\'" + index + "\'>" + index + "</option>");
  }
}

$(function() {
  $("#pageSelection").change(function() {
    var selectedText = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
    alert("Selected Text: " + selectedText + " Value: " + selectedValue);
  });
});

function addElement(parentId, elementTag, html) {
  var p = document.getElementById(parentId);
  var newElement = document.createElement(elementTag);
  newElement.innerHTML = html;
  p.prepend(newElement);
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="addElement('pageContent', 'div','Added Fruit');" value="Add an Item" />

<div id="pageContent">
  <div class="pageContentItem">Content01</div>
  <div class="pageContentItem">Content02</div>
  <div class="pageContentItem">Apple</div>
  <div class="pageContentItem">Mango</div>
  <div class="pageContentItem">Orange</div>
</div>

<select name="contentSelector" id="pageSelection">
  <option value="8">Apple</option>
  <option value="9">Mango</option>
  <option value="10">Orange</option>
</select>
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/yourpalnurav/pen/NmPQKJ?editors=1010) is available for easy trails.

Comment: Can you provide clarification about the option numbering, your two last statements suggest different approaches for the starting index. Also I would bind/render html based on an array and add elements using Array.unshift() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here below is Snippet which would help you ,

Modified the addElement Method to achieve the same.

```
function addElement(parentId, elementTag, html) {
  var p = document.getElementById(parentId);
  var newElement = document.createElement(elementTag);
  newElement.innerHTML = html;
  p.prepend(newElement);
  var elementValues = [];
  $("#pageContent").children().each(function () { 
    elementValues.push($(this).html()); 
  });
  $('#pageSelection').find('option').remove().end();
  $.each(elementValues, function( index, value ) {
    $('#pageSelection').append($('<option>', { value : index }).text(value));
  });
}
```

Here below is the updated code penURL:

https://codepen.io/redhatvicky/pen/jRPEXq?editors=1010